# Warning:(40, 5) Do not place Android context classes in static fields; this is a memory leak (and also breaks Instant Run)

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, static

Estou me deparando com esse aviso do Android Studio.
*Warning:(40, 5) Do not place Android context classes in static fields; this is a memory leak (and also breaks Instant Run)*
Eu tenho um botão que abre um fragment DatePicker para selecionar a data.

```
// Botão para chamar o DatePicker Fragment na Activity principal
    btnSelecionaData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
            newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
        }
    });
```

Ao selecionar a data eu passo essas informações para um EditText que fica na classe que chamou esse DatePicker Fragment com um .setText() mas para isso funcionar o EditText precisa ser **static** e por isso o Android Studio fica dando esse aviso.

```
// Classe DatePickerFragment
public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
        implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        // Do something with the date chosen by the user

        //######### ESTE É O EDITTEXT STATIC DA ACTIVITY PRINCIPAL, O QUAL EU PRECISO SETAR COM A DATA ASSIM QUE O USUÁRIO CLICAR NO OK DO FRAGMENT
        etAniver.setText(day+"/"+(month+1)+"/"+year);
        //#########
    }
}
```

Não entendo ainda 100% o funcionamento da linguagem, por isso pergunto...
Tem problema deixar assim como está?

Para mim parece que não tem problema, o valor da variável é necessária apenas enquanto o usuário está na activity pois assim que ele clicar em salvar os dados serão salvos no banco e o valor da variável não terá mais importância. Ao meu entender essa String vai ficar na memoria, depois será substituída pelo novo valor quando o usuário cadastrar outro cliente. Portanto a memoria ocupada por 1 variável estática seria insignificante... seria isso? Ou os dados que passam por essa variável se sobrepõem na memoria?

Comment: O `DatePickerFragment` está sendo usado pra alguma coisa? Por que não usar diretamente o `DatePickerDialog`?

Comment: Como e onde você declara `etAniver`?

Comment: Victor, etAniver fica fora do OnCreate na Activity principal, a qual chama o DatePicker.

Comment: Leonardo, não sei, procurei muito até achar esse funcional hahahaha

Comment: Essa classe retorna um DatePickerDialog, mas tem como criar esse DatePickerDialog dentro da activity principal?

Comment: Victor, etAniver é declarado desta forma: `public static EditText etAniver;`

Comment: Victor, a ligação entre a variável e o EditText é feita dentro do OnCreate dessa forma: `etAniver = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_aniver);`

Comment: Leonardo, tentei usar o DatePickerDialog direto mas meu projeto é para API 19 e para usar o OnDateSetListener eu preciso de API 24 acima

Comment: @PabloHenriqueCorrea Não coloque a solução do problema na resposta. O [pt.so] é um sistema de perguntas e respostas, então a resposta deve estar na área de respostas. Não há nenhum problema em responder a própria pergunta, então utilize o botão "Publique sua resposta" mais ao final da página. Também é desnecessário adicionar "Resolvido" no título Só de marcar uma resposta como aceita você já está indicando que o problema foi resolvido.

Comment: Obrigado Anderson, essa é minha primeira postagem.

Comment: Para resolver esse problema, basta seguir [essa resposta aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/206785/94862).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema (memory leak/vazamento de memória) apenas editando o método OnDateSet dentro da classe DatePickerFragment. Ficou assim:

```
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
    // Do something with the date chosen by the user
    TextView tv1= (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.et_aniver);
    tv1.setText(view.getDayOfMonth()+"/"+(view.getMonth()+1)+"/"+view.getYear());

}
```

Desta forma a variável do EditText na activity principal **não** precisa ser **static**, assim resolvendo o problema de (memory leak/vazamento de memória). A declaração ficou assim agora:

```
private EditText etAniver;
```

Comment: Pô, não consigo entender vocês, porque não pode escrever resolvido se o problema foi resolvido?? Isso torna tudo mais claro para aos leitores, facilita a leitura. E porque diabos eu não posso agradecer?? Foi apenas um obrigado ao pessoal que me ajudou. Vocês são anti-sociais??? Ou eu deixei passar alguma regra?

Comment: Não somos de forma alguma anti-sociais. Tudo tem haver como o stackoverflow funciona. Sugiro que lei-a o [*tour*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) e os tópicos da [Central de ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help). Se procurava uma resposta para resolver o *warning* deveria tê-la feito nesse sentido. No entanto, a forma como a fez ajudará muitos mais usuários, já que esse *warning* poderá surgir em muitas outras situação e não apenas nesse seu(tipo de) código.

Comment: Tranquilo, estou excluindo minha conta, não vejo fundamento em outras pessoas poderem alterar minhas postagens, é como pôr palavras na minha boca.

Answer (score 5):

> Tem problema deixar assim como está?

Sim tem.

Isso irá/poderá fazer com que a memória usada pela aplicação cresça progressivamente.

Isso acontece porque parte da memória alocada nesse processo não será libertada quando não mais for necessária(*memory leak*/vazamento de memória).

O problema reside no facto do EditText, assim como qualquer outro tipo de View, ter uma referência a um Context, provavelmente neste caso uma Activity.

Uma Activity, no decorrer do uso da aplicação, pode ser destruída e recriada pelo sistema.
Para que não exista em memória mais de uma mesma Activity, a memória alocada pela Activity destruída tem de poder ser libertada.

O EditText, ao ser declarado `static`, irá existir durante toda a existência da aplicação. Ao manter a referência à Activity, usada para o criar, não permitirá que a memória alocada para ela seja libertada, caso tenha sido criada outra.

Ou seja, o problema não está na quantidade de memória que ocupa o EditText mas sim nas instâncias que são referenciadas por ele que não podem ser libertadas quando não são mais precisas.

Comment: Muito obrigado seu Ramaral, foi extremamente esclarecedor.

Comment: Veja esta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/13761/2541) onde explica como fazer a comunicação entre o Fragment e a Activity .

Comment: Muito bom seu Ramaral, consegui entender um pouco mais a logica, mas ainda não consegui resolver pois o OnAttach foi deprecado e a nova forma de criar o DatePickerDialog eu não posso usar o `new OnDateSetListener()` pois é para API 24 acima e mau projeto é para API 19 acima

Comment: Apesar de obsoleto pode utilizar o `onAttach(Activity activity`. Em relação ao `OnDateSetListener()` não entendi o que quer dizer.

Comment: beleza vou tentar assim, com relação ao OnDateSetListener: Tem uma forma bem fácil de criar um DatePickerDialog com um OnDateSetListener mas só a partir da API 24, meu projeto é API 19, o código acredito que seria assim:

`DatePickerDialog datePicker = new DatePickerDialog(context, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                
            }
        })`

Comment: Agora entendi. Isso evitava ter de implementar o que é dito naquela resposta. Se reparar o principio é quase o mesmo.

Comment: Em relação ao método `onAttach(Activity activity)` use o `onAttach(Context context)`.

Comment: O querido, achei uma solução mais simples do que eu imaginava, já vou postar

Comment: Repare que a pergunta se refere ao *warning* e se "Tem problema deixar assim como está?". Por isso não cabe à resposta dar uma alternativa ao código postado.

Comment: Acredito que sim seu Ramaral, pois como o senhor respondeu a minha pergunta... "Tem problema deixar assim como está?" O senhor respondeu que tem, portanto temos um problema e o trecho de código alterado resolve exatamente esse problema (memory leak/vazamento de memória)

Comment: Se outra pessoa com o mesmo problema que eu lesse esse post já saberia resolver, agora sem o trecho alterado, as duvidas para as outras pessoas que acessarem permanece